# Proper settings to avoid blocking while scraping

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

For **scraping** the webiste I use [scraproxy](https://github.com/fabienvauchelles/scrapoxy) to create a pool of 15 proxies within 2 locations.

Website is auto-redirect (302) to reCapthca page when the request seems suspicious.

I use the following settings in scrapy. I was able to scrape only 741 page with relatively low speed (5 pages/min).

```
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 30.0
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 260.0
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = True
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 10
BLACKLIST_HTTP_STATUS_CODES = [302]
```

Any tips how can I avoid blacklisting? It seems that increasing the number of proxies can solve this problem, but maybe there is a space for improvements in settings as well.

Comment: You can also try adding a pool of different Headers.

Comment: I use header rotation as well

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford it, [Crawlera](https://scrapinghub.com/crawlera) is probably the best way to go.

Depending on the type of protection, however, using [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) might be enough.